# In EF core, after adding an entity in one class, how do I access the entity from a different class without calling SaveChanges()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a moderately complex create operation that has been broken up into multiple parts within the system I'm working on. Assume 3 classes:

- **OperationOrchestrator**
- **EntityCreator**
- **EntityModifier**

Using an instance of database context which is shared through DI (context is scoped per request), the **Orchestrator** will call on **Creator** and **Modifier** to build up a complex object and series of relationships, before eventually committing that operation.

My issue is that when the **EntityModifier** tries to access the entity created through **EntityCreator**, I come up on a "Sequence contains no elements" exception. Some pseudocode to illustrate:

```
public class OperationOrchestrator
{
   private IContext _context;
   private IEntityCreator _entityCreator, 
   private IEntityModifier _entityModifier

   public OperationOrchestrator(
       IContext context, 
       IEntityCreator entityCreator, 
       IEntityModifier entityModifier
   )
   {
      //boilerplate var assignment code
   }

   public void CreatePerson(string name, int age)
   {
       var id = _entityCreator.CreatePerson(name);
       _entityModifier.UpdatePersonAge(id, age);
       _context.SaveChanges();
   }
}

public class EntityCreator : IEntityCreator 
{
   private IContext _context;

   public EntityCreator (
       IContext context
   )
   {
      _context = context;
   }

   public Guid CreatePerson(string name)
   {
       var person = new Person {
          Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
          Name = name
       };

       _context.Add(person);
       return person.Id;

   }
}

public class EntityModifier : IEntityModifier
{
   private IContext _context;

   public EntityModifier (
       IContext context
   )
   {
      _context = context;
   }

   public void UpdatePersonAge(Guid id, int age)
   {
       var person = _context.People.Single(x => x.Id == id);
       person.Age = age;
   }
}
```

The problem call here is at `context.People.Single(x => x.Id == id);`. It appears that the context hasn't added the new person to its People DbSet even though the instance of context should be the same across classes. On top of that, if I debug and inspect local variables, I can see newly created person in the context's ChangeTracker.

Finally, if I call `SaveChanges()` within the `UpdatePersonAge()` method, just before making the call to `context.People.Single(x => x.Id == id);`, the attempt to retrieve the person immediately after will succeed.

Is this intended design for Entity Framework or is there some configuration option that I can set to override this behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may be a victim of EF's caching. Try http://codethug.com/2016/02/19/Entity-Framework-Cache-Busting/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design according to [summary from DbSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1?view=efcore-3.1):

> The results of a LINQ query against a DbSet{TEntity} will contain the results
>               returned from the database and may not reflect changes made in the context that have not
>                been persisted to the database. For example, the results will not contain newly added entities
>               and may still contain entities that are marked for deletion.

You can check for entity in ChangeTracker first and then if where is none you can go to db. This will also reduce amount of queries your application will generate.

```
public class EntityModifier : IEntityModifier
{
    private IContext _context;

    public EntityModifier(IContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void UpdatePersonAge(Guid id, int age)
    {
        var person = _context.ChangeTracker.Entries<Person>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id) ??
                     _context.People.Single(x => x.Id == id);
        person.Age = age;
    }
}
```